# When using Google Apps, is it possible to have multiple email addresses without being charged as additional users?

Tags: google, google-workspace

[Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/), now charges $5/mo/user.  I would like to create multiple email addresses info@, sales@, etc... but all go to the same mailbox (me).

Is there a way to go about this without essentially paying $5.00/email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create up to 30 Email aliases per user account.

An email alias is an alternative email address that points to an existing user account. For example, the user bill@subsidiary.com might also want to receive email addressed to william@subsidiary.com. If you create william@subsidiary.com as an email alias for bill@subsidiary.com, Google Apps will deliver email for both of these addresses to the same Gmail inbox.

More info here: [Email aliases on Google Apps](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33327) and here: [adding email aliases](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182527)